# useEffect never stops running

Tags: reactjs, reload, use-effect

I am sure this question has been asked a million times. And I have looked at at least 50% of the replies. But none work for me.

I have this component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { FormPaper, FormWrapper } from "teton-frontend-components/dist";
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import Network from "./Network";
import { TetonButton } from "teton-frontend-components";
import useDeepCompareEffect from "./deepCompare";

const logo = require("./timer.png");

function App() {
    const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);
    const [word, setWord] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [id, setId] = useState("");

    useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
        Network.getWordIds().then(ids => {
            setIds(ids.data.data);
        });
    }, []);

    useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
        const id = window.location.href.split("/")[window.location.href.split("/").length - 1];
        if (id) {
            getWordWithId(id);
        }
    }, [])

    const getWord = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const id = ids[Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length)]._id;
        Network.getWordById(id).then(word => {
            const href = window.location.href;
            window.location.href = href.split("/")[0] + id;
            setWord(word.data.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        }).finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
    };

    const getWordWithId = id => {
        Network.getWordById(id).then(word => {
            const href = window.location.href;
            window.location.href = href.split("/")[0] + id;
            setWord(word.data.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        }).finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <FormPaper width={"30%"} margin={"5% auto"} logo={logo} children={
                <div>
                    <FormWrapper children={
                        <div>
                            <p>Encavis Zusammenhalt Tabu</p>
                            <br/>
                            Wort
                            <br/>
                            <TextField color={"primary"} disabled={true} variant={"outlined"}
                                       style={{margin: "0 0 2% 0"}} value={word.word}/>
                            <br/>
                            Verbotene Wörter
                            <br/>
                            <TextField color={"primary"} disabled={true} variant={"outlined"}
                                       value={word.taboos ? word.taboos[0] : ""}/>
                            <br/>
                            <TextField color={"primary"} disabled={true} variant={"outlined"}
                                       value={word.taboos ? word.taboos[1] : ""}/>
                            <br/>
                            <TextField color={"primary"} disabled={true} variant={"outlined"}
                                       value={word.taboos ? word.taboos[2] : ""}/>
                            <br/>
                            <TextField color={"primary"} disabled={true} variant={"outlined"}
                                       value={word.taboos ? word.taboos[3] : ""}/>
                            <br/>
                            <TextField color={"primary"} disabled={true} variant={"outlined"}
                                       value={word.taboos ? word.taboos[4] : ""}/>
                            <br/>
                            <TetonButton text={"Neues Wort"} variant={"contained"} color={"primary"}
                                         onClick={() => getWord()} disabled={false} loading={loading}
                                         margin={"2% 0 0 0"}/>
                        </div>
                    }/>
                </div>
            }/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I want to click the button, then fetch a word and set it into the fields. This works well. I also need the `href` param not to be ignored because I need the page to load the id in the `href` when the page is loaded with that id. However when the button was clicked I do not want that to happen. So I have read that [] as dependency array for use effect will only run once on render. Now however, once the button is clicked or the page is loaded with id in `href`, I get infinite reloads. How can I stop this? The `deepCompare` is just so I can also check objects. Also I tried all combinations of dependency arrays. This just seems to hate me.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Deep Compare Code

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const deepCompareEquals = (a, b) => {
    return _.isEqual(a, b);
};

const useDeepCompareMemoize = value => {
    const ref = useRef();

    if (!deepCompareEquals(value, ref.current)) {
        ref.current = value
    }

    return ref.current
};

const useDeepCompareEffect = (callback, dependencies) => {
    useEffect(callback, useDeepCompareMemoize(dependencies));
};

export default useDeepCompareEffect;
```

Comment: can you post the `deepCompare` code too?

Comment: Try replacing useDeepCompareEffect with useEffect and check if the same behavior is replicated?

Comment: It is. The useDeepCompareEffect was just an attempt to fix it. The behavior is the same however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just spotted it.

You are using `window.location.href = href.split("/")[0] + id;` which will always reload the page and of course this will end in the problem you mentioned.

You must use `react router` for these things.

Comment: Thank you! I am sure that react router would make it better. I cannot see how though. I replaced my logic with useLocation and location.pathname to get the parameter I need. But the page still reloads without stoping. Adding the Path and word as dependencies to the hook does not change that either. Could you maybe give me a quick example of how it needs to be implemented?

Comment: @Timbo search for `history.push`. This will do the work

Comment: You have saved my life! Thank you very much. It is very obvious. I just did not see it. 
I replaced ```window.location.href = href.split("/")[0] + id;``` with ```history.push(window.location.href.split("/")[0] + id);```

Comment: glaad i helped :)

Comment: I would NEVER have found that. A thousand blessings on your house!